# AngularJS: triggering view loading from child window (OAuth)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth

I'm all but sure this is the best practice to achieve my objective (manage OAuth in AngularJS) but here it is what I've done and what doesn't work:

By using **Hello.js** (injected in Angular through **angular-global-injector**) I managed to open the OAuth popup window (in my case Google+) by using the following code in my **controllers.js** file.

```
  hello.init({
        google: MY_APPLICATION_ID
    },{redirect_uri:'app/_partials/'});

     $scope.doLogin = function(network) {
         console.log('Calling hello ' + network);
         hello.login(network,function(r){ // callback
            console.log("login successful..");
         });
     };
```

The pop-up with login request opens (note that I had to use a "fake" index.html view since $routerProvider doesn't seem to work properly on URI-redict on the child window (page not found, but the URI /auth would world normally on the parent window..since all the others routers work flawlessly on it. So I can't only guess the problem is with the child window.).
This way instead the index.html is loaded since the redirect is done as AngularJS wasn't there.

Here is my route configuration.

```
    $routeProvider.
        when("/userLogin", {templateUrl: "_partials/userLogin.html", controller: "webClientController"})
        .when("/dialInterface", {templateUrl: "_partials/dialInterface.html", controller: "webClientController"})
        .when("/error404", {templateUrl: "_partials/error404.html", controller: "webClientController"})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/error404'});
```

Here is the content of my popup window (the fake "index.html").

```
<!-- temp workaround to manage oAuth since routeProvider doesn't match the REDIRECT URI correctly -->

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#go-to-dial-interface",opener.document).trigger('click');
    window.close();
</script>
```

And here is the code of the view (loaded correctly by AngularJS) /userLogin

```
<md-content class="md-padding md-primary" style="height: 600px;padding: 24px;" layout-fill>
    <a ng-click="doLogin('google')" class="zocial googleplus">Sign in with Google+</a>
</md-content>


<a id="go-to-dial-interface" href="#dialInterface" style="visibility:hidden;"></a>
```

Basicly the **logic** (and the problem) is:

1. The user clicks on the **a** tag which leads to execution of **doLogin('google')** (this calls the function in the controller which contains the call to Hello.js)
2. A Google account is chosen, afterwards there is the redirect (in this case to the "fake" index.html since I don't manage it with Angular routes
3. this index.html is loaded properly in the OAuth popup and the javascript code is executed correctly: trigger go-to-dial-interface's click() event and close the OAuth popup
4. The triggered click() event is supposed to cause a redirect in the main window to a new view (#dialInterface) but it doesn't: the current view (userLogin) is reloaded (or perhaps not..) and the new one doesn't (of course the URL in the browser address bar doesn't change)

Any better solution / improvement is also well accepted.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have the webClientController ready for the /dialInterface view?
Any console errors?

Comment: The error you're experiencing could be because you either don't have a webClientController anywhere (yet your code needs it) or there's some issue with it. Ready means it's created: written; script file is loaded into the DOM; an angular module has been instantiated; the webClientController has been attached to that module; etc.

Comment: of there's a controller attached to the view. indeed the "root" view (useLogin) is loading correctly and if I type MANUALLY the name of another view (like #/somepage) and I set the routing it simply works